# Magento - this javascript file doesn't merge correctly

Tags: javascript, optimization, drop-down-menu, magento-1.6

i have a magento 1.6.2 webshop.

I would like to merge the javascript files for optimizing my loadingspeeds.
But when i select merge in the settings my Custom Menu extensions doesn't work anymore.

I guess there is something wrong in the code.
I have tried to contact the developer, but i don't get a reaction ...

This extension is for the navigation menu at the top (with images)

Here is the code of the custommenu.js file:

```
    function wpShowMenuPopup(objMenu, popupId)
{
    objMenu = $(objMenu.id); var popup = $(popupId); if (!popup) return;
    popup.style.display = 'block';
    objMenu.addClassName('active');
    var popupWidth = CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_WIDTH;
    if (!popupWidth) popupWidth = popup.getWidth();
    var pos = wpPopupPos(objMenu, popupWidth);
    popup.style.top = pos.top + 'px';
    popup.style.left = pos.left + 'px';
    if (CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_WIDTH) popup.style.width = CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_WIDTH + 'px';
}

function wpPopupPos(objMenu, w)
{
    var pos = objMenu.cumulativeOffset();
    var wraper = $('custommenu');
    var posWraper = wraper.cumulativeOffset();
    var wWraper = wraper.getWidth() - CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_RIGHT_OFFSET_MIN;
    var xTop = pos.top - posWraper.top + CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_TOP_OFFSET;
    var xLeft = pos.left - posWraper.left;
    if ((xLeft + w) > wWraper) xLeft = wWraper - w;
    return {'top': xTop, 'left': xLeft};
}

function wpHideMenuPopup(element, event, popupId, menuId)
{
    element = $(element.id); var popup = $(popupId); if (!popup) return;
    var current_mouse_target = null;
    if (event.toElement)
    {
        current_mouse_target = event.toElement;
    }
    else if (event.relatedTarget)
    {
        current_mouse_target = event.relatedTarget;
    }
    if (!wpIsChildOf(element, current_mouse_target) && element != current_mouse_target)
    {
        if (!wpIsChildOf(popup, current_mouse_target) && popup != current_mouse_target)
        {
            popup.style.display = 'none';
            $(menuId).removeClassName('active');
        }
    }
}

function wpIsChildOf(parent, child)
{
    if (child != null)
    {
        while (child.parentNode)
        {
            if ((child = child.parentNode) == parent)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can see it working on my webshop: [www.liefstoereigenwijs.nl](http://www.liefstoereigenwijs.nl)

Can anyone see if there is something wrong in the code?
Or has a other solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is automatically solved in 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 0):

End each

```
function xx(x)
{
  ...
}
```

with a `;` at the end!

So:

```
function xx(x)
{
  ...
};
```

Comment: unfortunatly this isn't the solution to my problem